# React app get stuck on reload on Firefox desktop, but not on Chrome and other browsers

Tags: reactjs, flask, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app build being served by flask. It works fine in other browsers; however on Firefox, when I do a reload, the main.js file is stuck at the `fetch` method. After 3 minutes, it timesout then renders what it suppose to. I am looking for guidance on where to look from hereon. The production server does not log that the endpoint is receiving the fetch request; however, once the 3 minutes is up, the client side renders the updated information (as if it hit the server side). Everything looks like it should be working in the code I wrote, but I am not able scope out where I should be looking in debugging this issue.

Note: I am giving a broad description of the problem at the moment, but will disclose specifics such as codes, logs, and others items once I am able to get some guidance of the matter. As of now, there are no resources pointing out this specific issue, thus displaying code will simply be a "garbage" dump.

Comment: Post some code if you want answers.

Answer (score 0):

After working on the problem for quite some time, we found these two articles to be very helpful:

1. https://www.andreasreiterer.at/fix-whitescreen-static-react-app/
2. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react--flask-project

After testing different sources, we first found that article one's suggestion of changing the homepage to the base url worked. After realizing that the nginx was getting confused on which static files to server, we proceeded to follow article 2's steps.

We did not have any issues on other browsers, but only on firefox. I hope this will help those that are experiencing the same Firefox issue.